# Networking Sockets Theory

Tags: sockets, networking, packet

If two devices with different IP addresses send UDP packets through processes with different ports to the same destination device and on the same destination port, will the two packets be received by the same socket?

Comment: Yes...the receiving socket will be the same for both packets.

Comment: A socket is a combination of IP address and a port number. As log as these things are same they will represent same socket.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the source address isn't relevant for UDP.